# Branching in visual studio moves wrong dll's

Tags: visual-studio, branching-and-merging

I have a main branch in Visual Studio where my project uses Microsoft.reportViewer dll's with version 10.x.x.x, but when I branch the project to a new branch, ex. from main to production, the Microsoft.ReportViewer dll's get updated to version 12.x.x.x

Why does it do this?

I have to manually check the dll's everytime i branch and I wan't it to do it correctly.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is there really nobody who can answer my question?

Comment: I could really use some help on this issue.